# How to make this ActiveRecord call more efficient with Rails 6.0.3.3 and Ruby 2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My app has the following models used in this example

- Member
- Prayer Requests
- Prayers
- Journal
- Journal Entries

What I am trying to do is show the number of prayer_requests and prayers done on the same day as a journal entry. I have tried adding code to the model, to the controller or directly in the view and each time it always needs to do extra calls for each entry when displaying them in the view. So, I have gotten it to work, but on the show page for the journal, it does three db calls just to get to the page (member, profile, and journal entries) and then two additional calls for each entry (prayer_requests and prayers). The requests, prayers, and journal are all connected to the member model and the journal entry is connected through the journal to the member. There has to be a more efficient way to do this with eager loading. Any help on how to change my models or ActiveRecord calls would be appreciated.

**Member Model**

```
class Member < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile, dependent: :destroy
  
  has_one  :prayer_journal
  has_many :journal_entries, through: :prayer_journal

  has_many :prayer_requests    
  has_many :prayer_request_shares, foreign_key: "shared_with_id"
  has_many :shared_prayer_requests, through: :prayer_request_shares, source: :prayer_request

  has_many :prayers
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  def daily_prayer_count(date)
    self.prayers.where("date(created_at) = ?", date).count
  end

  def daily_request_count(date)
    self.prayer_requests.where("date(created_at) = ?", date).count
  end
end
```

**Prayer Journal Model**

```
class PrayerJournal < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :member
  has_many :journal_entries
end
```

**Journal Entry Model**

```
class JournalEntry < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :prayer_journal

  encrypts :content

  validates :content, presence: true  

  has_many :prayer_requests, :through => :member
  has_many :prayer_request_updates, :through => :prayer_requests
  has_many :prayers, :through => :member

  def request_count(requests)
    requests.where("date(created_at) = ?", self.created_at).count
  end

  def prayer_count(prayers)
    prayers.where("date(created_at) = ?", self.created_at).count
  end
end
```

**Journal Controller**

```
class PrayerJournalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_member

  def show
    @prayer_journal = current_member.prayer_journal
    @journal_entries = @prayer_journal.journal_entries.group_by_day(format: "%a, %B %d, %Y", reverse: true) { |u| u.created_at }
  end
end
```

**Journal Show View**

```
<% if @journal_entries.any? %>
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-lg-10">
      <% @journal_entries.each do |date, entries| %>
        <h2 class="post-archive-item mb-3"><%= date %></h2>
        <%= pluralize(daily_prayer_count(date), "prayer") given %>
        <%= pluralize(daily_request_count(date), "requests") made %>
        <% entries.each do |journal_entry| %>
          <span class="post-archive-meta">
            <span class="post-archive-meta-details">
              <p class="post-archive-meta-details-date font-weight-bold mb-1">
                <span class="convert-utc-to-time-zone align-middle" style="text-decoration: underline;"><%= journal_entry.created_at %></span>
                <%= link_to "Edit", edit_journal_entry_path(journal_entry), class: 'badge badge-pill badge-primary' %>
              </p>
            </span>
          </span>
          <%= simple_format(journal_entry.content) %>          
        <% end %>
        <hr class="my-5" />

      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% else %>
  <div class="text-center">
    <p class="lead">Create your first Journal Entry</p>
    <%= link_to 'New Journal Entry', new_journal_entry_path, class: "btn btn-primary", style:"color:white;" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you please split that wall of text into paragraphs? And maybe provide an example of the desired output? As is its borderline unreadable.

Comment: Look into using `includes` for eager loading, will speed things up massively https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: I think the solution here most likely is not eager loading though - use a custom select clause to select an aggregate. There really is no reason to load a bunch of records if all you want is a count. Knowing which RDBMS is in use would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want here is to just select aggregates instead of eager loading.

```
class JournalEntry < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :member, though: :prayer_journal

  def self.with_prayer_count(date)
    prayers = Prayer.arel_table

    subquery = Prayer.arel_table.then do |prayers|
      prayers.project(prayers[Arel.star].count)
             .where(
                prayers['member_id'].eq('members.id').and(
                  prayers['date'].eq(date)
                )
             )
             .as('prayer_count')
    end

    joins(:member)
      .select(
        arel_table[Arel.star],
        subquery 
      )
  end
end
```

This example uses a subquery:

```
(SELECT COUNT(prayers.*) FROM prayers WHERE prayers.member_id = members.id AND prayers.date = ?) AS prayer_count
```

Depending on what RDBMS you using their may be other approaches such as window functions or lateral joins to achieve the same goal.